# SQL query shows every result 3 times

Tags: sql, database, filter

I have this code which should give me results based on the category_id = 2 but somehow i get the right results but tripled. How can I prevent this. Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM partner_categories 
JOIN partner
ON partner_categories.category_id = partner.category_id
WHERE partner.category_id = "2" AND partner.status = 1 ORDER BY 
partner_name ASC
```

And here's what I get:
[image]

And this is the browser version:
[image]

So every partner_name is tripled. Why?

Please write a comment if I have to post any other information and thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not duplicates: the `partnet_id`s are not the same. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, so one can understand what you are after.

Comment: I added a photo of the results in the browser. I don't really understand what you need. Can you explain? I'm a newbie in SQL.

Comment: Please don't post images of technical information like sample data or results. We need formatted text here if you want to get a good, prompt answer.

Answer (score 2):

Got it by myself. Just had to define also the partner_id because it's in both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM partner_categories
JOIN partner
ON partner_categories.category_id = partner.category_id 
AND partner_categories.partner_id = partner.partner_id
WHERE partner.category_id = "2" 
AND partner.status = 1 
ORDER BY partner_name ASC
```